# Put different images to child items in expandable list view

Tags: android, image, expandablelistview

I am trying to put different images into the child items. For that I did a if-else statement to assign the appropriate image to the child/ childposition. This works so far but when I expand e. g. another parent then the images also will be inserted to other child items.

Here the relevant `getChildView() Method` in my class which extends from `BaseExpandableListAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.image_child);

        if (childText.equals("String1")) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_1);

        } else if (childText.equals("String2")) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_2);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

I also did try to compare it directly with the childposition isntead of the string value, but still same issue. Some ideas? 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CHECK THIS [LINK](https://github.com/harishsn/ExpandableListView) !

TODO:
Use 2D array to pass image resourse id to Child View or any other methods.

Like this...

`int[][] images = {{R.id.img_1_1, R.id.img_1_2,},{R.id.2_1, R.id.2_2}};`

Refer getGroupView() in CustomELVAdapter you will understand.